# Defining a method that is strongly typed and allows only inherited types

Tags: c#, strong-typing

I want to define a method for a class Dev that must be strongly typed and allows only types
inherited from the class Dev that uses a constructor with no parameter.
The following is what I came up with:

```
class Dev
{
    public static void Interview<T>(T target) where T : Dev
    {

    }
}
```

An alternative is:

```
class Dev
    {
        public static void Interview<T>(T target) where T : Dev, new()
        {
    
        }
    }
```

Not sure if any of the above is correct or what difference adding the new() make.
I am not sure if it satisfies both the conditions 1. strongly typed 2. allow inherited typed

Comment: Why don't you write up some test cases to assess your assumptions?

Comment: Another approach is to pass creator function to your method, so the responsibility of instantiating it are delegated to the caller. Caller has all the information about the actual type and how to create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class or method declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

**Apply the new constraint to a type parameter when a generic class creates new instances of the type**

See [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)